# ODI selective Reverse Engineering through groovy script

Tags: groovy, sdk, oracle-data-integrator

I try to use ODI-SDK with groovy scripting to automate **selective** reverse-engineering datastores to model. To do this, i used following script doStandardReverse() method, but getting error. I am trying to execute below script.
I have used API mentioned in below documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/core/service/reverse/ReverseService.html

```
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiProjectFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.finder.IOdiDataStoreFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.finder.IOdiModelFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModel
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModelFolder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModel.ReverseObjectType
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiFolderFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiUserProcedureFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiKMFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.finder.IMappingFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.adapter.project.IKnowledgeModule.ProcessingType
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.finder.IOdiContextFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.finder.IOdiLogicalSchemaFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.finder.IOdiTechnologyFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiContext
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiTechnology
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiLogicalSchema
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiDataStore
import oracle.odi.domain.xrefs.expression.Expression
import oracle.odi.domain.xrefs.expression.Expression.SqlGroupType
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiProcedureLine.LogCounter
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiProcedureLineCmd
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiUserProcedure
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiUserProcedureLine
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiPackage
import oracle.odi.core.persistence.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition
import oracle.odi.core.service.reverse.ReverseService
import oracle.odi.domain.project.StepModel.ReverseModel

txnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
tm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager()
tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef)

def myList = ["SNP_CHECK_TAB","SRC_CITY"]


OdiModel srcModel = ((IOdiModelFinder)tme.getFinder(OdiModel.class)).findByCode("TEST_MOD");

//call reverse engeneering
rs = new ReverseService();

rm = rs.doStandardReverse(odiInstance, srcModel.getModelId(), ReverseService.DataStoreSelection.SELECTED, myList);

println('Data Store/s created.');


tm.commit(txnStatus)
```

I am getting error below

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to oracle.odi.core.service.reverse.OdiDataStoreNameAndType
(Subtract 18 from the error line number to account for the standard imports)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to oracle.odi.core.service.reverse.OdiDataStoreNameAndType
    at oracle.odi.core.service.reverse.ReverseService.convertDataStoreListToSnpsStringPair(ReverseService.java:452)
    at oracle.odi.core.service.reverse.ReverseService.doStandardReverse(ReverseService.java:169)
    at oracle.odi.core.service.reverse.ReverseService$doStandardReverse.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at di.run(di.groovy:61)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:518)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:497)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:170)
    at oracle.di.studio.groovy.GroovyScriptRunInstance.run(GroovyScriptRunInstance.java:222)
Script exited.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains Strings where it should contain [OdiDataStore](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/model/OdiDataStore.html) objects.

findByName method of interface [IOdiDataStoreFinder](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/model/finder/IOdiDataStoreFinder.html#findByName-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) can be used to find a specific OdiDataStore object.